# DELPHI Change Property of Object stored in Variable

Tags: delphi, variables, properties, timage

Is there a way to change the property of a `TImage` which is stored in a variable?

I have a function that writes the `Name` propery of a `TImage` in the `FigureSelectedName` variable, and it writes the field Name in the `FieldSelected` variable.

Now my problem is:

```
FieldSelectedName.top
FieldSelectedName.left
```

This gives a error in Delphi (*Illegal qualifier*)

```
function moveFigure(FigName:String; FieldName:String):boolean;
var
  x:Integer;
  y:Integer;
begin
  if (FigureSelected=true) and (FieldSelected=true) then
   begin
     x := strtoint(FieldSelectedName[2]);
     y := Ord(FieldSelectedName[1])-64;

     FigureSelectedName.top  := 80 + (x * 70);
     FigureSelectedName.left := 80 + (y * 70);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: `FieldSelected` in your code is a `Boolean` so it can't have any `top` or whatsoever other property

Comment: None of this makes a lot of sense. I guess you have a string and want to find a variable of that name. You need to know which scope you want to search? Where do you intend to look for this variable?

Comment: @fantaghirocco Sorry I meant FieldSelectedName wich contains the name of a TImage...
And I want to move the Image to some Coordinates.    


I am not searching for a Variable, I have a Variable containing the Name of a TImage and want to move the TImage to some Coordinates.
But this function shall be used for different TImages thats why I want to replace the TImage Name with a Variable.

Comment: Where do you intend to look for the variable? In which scope? Why are you programming using names? Usually people do that by mistake.

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong. If you need to change properties of an object inside a procedure, pass the object in as a parameter to the procedure. Trying to change it by looking it up by name is simply wrong, it adds unnecessary overhead, it leads to hard-to-debug problems, and it makes the code impossible to maintain,especially for other programmers who inherit your code in the future. Design it properly in the first place, instead of trying to solve the wrong problem afterward.

Comment: FigureSelectedName contains a Name of an TImage Object wich is has been selected, I used this approach since I have it defined as a gloabal Variable because i use it for multiple Purposes...

Comment: @KS_HTK - If you MUST use a Global variable (bad idea), make it of TImage, or TObject, not string - the NAME is irrelevant, the reference (address) is.

Comment: @Gerry Figured that out now, got it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) can be used to find a component in a form knowing its name.

- check if what was found is really a `TImage`
- use the `TImage` properties and methods

---

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  comp: TComponent;
  img: TImage;
begin
  comp := FindComponent('Image1');
  if comp is TImage then begin
    img := TImage(comp);
    img.Left := 0;
    img.Top := 0;
  end;
end;
```

---

Your method should be written like this, for the `FindComponent` method to work.

```
function moveFigure(FigName:String; FieldName:String): Boolean;
var
  x:Integer;
  y:Integer;
  comp: TComponent;
  img: TImage;
begin
  //Result := False;
  if FigureSelected and FieldSelected then
  begin
    x := strtoint(FieldSelectedName[2]);
    y := Ord(FieldSelectedName[1])-64;

    comp := Form1.FindComponent(FieldSelectedName);
    if comp is TImage then begin
      img := TImage(comp);
      img.Left := 80 + (y * 70);
      img.Top := 80 + (x * 70);
      //Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But the method has many issues:

- the method's arguments `FigName:String` and `FieldName:String` are never used in the method body
- are you sure the coordinates you're looking for in the image's name will be ever only one digit long?
- `Ord(FieldSelectedName[1])`: an ordinal of a `Char` looks like a strange value for the Y-axis
- the method is declared returning `Boolean` but doesn't provide a value for the `Result`

Comment: Yes, but by and large this is a bad idea. Runtime introspection is useful when compile time options are not practical.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the bad idea is in the question but feel free to provide a good idea ;-)

Comment: Of course that is so. But you didn't even attempt to warn the asker of the risks.

Comment: Anyway, I removed the spurious test that `comp` is assigned. That is contained in the `is` test.

Comment: @DavidH I didn't warn the OP because of your comment *Usually people do that by mistake* already does it. Thank you for the edit

Comment: This wont work, since i want to edit a different Image every time the procedure runs.

Comment: @KS What makes you think that the code here can operate only on a single image?

Comment: @fant This is what happens when you answer really poor questions. Frankly, in my experience, it's a waste of time to do so. The best thing is to close them and try to keep the site clean.

Comment: @DavidH I agree but on the other hand, I had one of the most obvious answers provided the most voted up by now... so maybe is it a matter of weather? :D

Answer (score 0):

Changing the system from using the `TImage` Names in the variable to having a `TImage` pointer in the variable did the trick.

```
FigureSelectedImage: TImage;
FieldSelectedImage:  TImage;
```

Then using the variable and the normal identifiers works fine.

```
FigureSelectedImage.Top := ...
```

Comment: This is absolutely how to solve your problem, but it does not answer the question you asked.